# Is there any other way to provide a Remote(GitHub) path for deploying the application/code to an AWS region while using the cloud-formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing server-less application(SAM). I have try to create new stack in region using cloud-formation and deploy a application jar using CodeUri. But the Remote(GitHub) path doesn't support in CodeUri. Is there any other way to provide Remote(GitHub) path to deploy the application/code to AWS region?

Could anyone tell me, How to specified the GitHub path in cloud-formation template?

Answer (score 0):

Create a lambda application. choose code repo from github, then the cloud-formation will create a private repo for you automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).